# Seleccionar columnas con una condición pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

tengo un dilema... tengo las siguientes variables: calorias, proteina, grasa, sodio,    fibra dietaria, carbohidratos, azúcar, potasio, vitaminas y minerales.

A su vez tengo unos fabricantes: Kelloggs, Quaker Oats, General Mills, etc.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando crear una función que tenga como argumentos el fabricante y la variable:

```
def valor_medio_intervalo(fabricante, variable):
subconjunto = cereal_df[(cereal_df['fabricante']== fabricante)&(cereal_df['calorias']==variable)]
```

Pero cuando retorno el subconjunto, no me sale lo que corresponde a lo ingresado en "variable", me ayudan por favor. Este es el error:

```
2902         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'calorias'
```

Comment: El error dice que no existe una columna llamada `calotias` verifica el nombre. También sería de ayuda que pusieras tu dataframe

Comment: Listo, ya agregué el dataframe... caí en cuenta que no es "calorias", sino más bien que esa parte debe ser dinámica

Comment: Verific el nombre (si tiene espscios), por que el error dice que no existe la columna `calorias`